# Creating a fresh node.js Facebook app on Heroku results in application error

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, heroku

I just created a fresh new Node.js Facebook app, hosted on Heroku. When I browse to my application however, it shows me the following error:

[image: error message on heroku]

When I clone a copy of the application to my computer and check the logs, I see the following error:

http://pastebin.com/qMYEyWWq

Again, I did not touch any code yet. I'm new to Node.js, does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same pb...

Answer (score 1):

The error code:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token S
2013-04-12T08:24:48.218425+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.parse (native)
```

suggest you are having a problem parsing the response from Facebook. Then heroku closes the connection to the script. Try reviewing the IncomingMessage payload for a hint.

```
code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response"
```

Comment: The error seems to arise in the restler.js library. I'm not very familiar with this yet. Not sure what to inspect to get any further.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue. Try logging out of facebook, you'll likely see the app working fine but when you login - Application Error

Is this what's going on with you too?